# Use Try and Catch in a method to verify HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, methods, return, httpwebrequest

I am learning C #, with this class I get information in JSON from an API, then from the form I call my class "MyClass" to put the values in the corresponding fields, but I do not know how to detect if the connection with the API was unsuccessful, I know that try and catch must be used and that's why I put it in my "MyClass" class but I do not know how to do the verification correctly:

I have these defined classes:

```
public class Lawyer
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string numdoc { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
}

public class Worker
{
    public string time { get; set; }
    public string service { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string Condition { get; set; }
    public string PLE { get; set; }
    public List<Lawyer> lawyers { get; set; }
    public List<Worker> workers { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

And it is my "MyClass" (I tried using the "try" and the "catch" but I do not know if it is the correct way to do it...):

```
class MyClass 
{
    public RootObject MyMethod(int inRUC){
  try {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://www.example.com/api/?get=" + inRUC);
        HttpWebResponse response;

        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        {
            var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        }
      }
  catch (Exception)
        {
         return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the section of my form that calls the class, it works fine but I do not know how to verify from here that the connection with the API was successful:

```
private void Button1_ClickBefore(object sboObject, SAPbouiCOM.SBOItemEventArg pVal, out bool BubbleEvent)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRuc1.Value.ToString()))
    {
        BubbleEvent = false;
    }
    else
    {
        BubbleEvent = true;

        int para = 0;
        int.TryParse(txtRuc1.Value, out para);

        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        EditText1.Value = obj.MyMethod(para).result.name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not do this:

```
catch (Exception)
{
    return null;
}
```

This will simply "swallow" any runtime errors. If the connection fails, `obj.MyMethod(para).result.name;` will give you a NullpointerException that doesn't tell you what exactly went wrong. Instead take a look at what could possibly go wrong within "MyMethod" and which specific exceptions that would cause. Catch only exceptions that you know how to handle. If you don't (yet) know how to handle a specific exception, don't catch it. This will cause your program to crash with a somewhat meaningful error message. Work your your way from there. Try everything you can come up with to make the connection fail and observe which exceptions are thrown, so you might come up with a way to prevent those situations or recover from them.

Comment: This might seem like a too broad and unspecific answer, but I think the question is pretty fundamental and a bit of fundamental advice might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your doubt is right. This is not correct way to handle exception in your case.

You should use `WebException` which will give you an opportunity to read the response sent by server. Here, you can check details of the errorsome response received from the API and take appropriate action. Below is sample code for your reference. You can tweak it to your need.

```
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    string text = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
        }
```

You can get more details about WbeException from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webexception?view=netframework-4.7.2

And some more details with code sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/handling-errors

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a class just for a method. You can put this method aside your UI event handler - if it is used only there. Or create a static helper class for all your API calls - or not static if you are reusing something between calls, like cookies. But then create an instance for the whole UI or at most for the form.

Please note, that API call might succeed technically and you still get an error message back. Check `StatusCode` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode?view=netframework-4.7.2) before trying to deserialize. You will most likely get `IOException` or `WebException` if there is a network or http level problem. If the server code is faulting or you passed invalid parameters, you will get a status code different than 200 (OK) - there are other success status codes trough. But you can get also content parsing exceptions. Always log such exceptions, even temporarily, but never handle with just noticing it!

But I suggest you using `HttpClient` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) instead with `HttpContentExtensions` [methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontentextensions(v=vs.118).aspx). There are many advantages, as this is optimized for API calls and it supports async for all operations. And the later package makes it easy to handle custom objects when reading or sending with any method. Beware, `HttpClient` instances are [optimized](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) for reusability even across threads - thus you can have only one or few in your application. Unfortunately, I haven't found any complete tutorial in this topic to link to.